# Using Webpack with d3, jQuery, and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, webpack

Hey guys,

Total Webpack (and es6/modern frontend practices) newbie here, so sorry if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to build a d3 dataviz project using modern web dev standards and am having a lot of trouble getting it up and running -- specifically, I'm getting a weird Uncaught (in promise) TypeError when I launch the local webpack dev server, and none of my d3 elements are displaying. I'm sure it's something very dumb that I'm overlooking but I've been scouring the internet for what feels like forever and unfortunately haven't made any progress. Any guidance would be so, so appreciated.

Full disclosure: this is for a college course, but my teacher knows nothing about modern webdev standards, so I am fully on my own in choosing to develop it this way. I just wanted to give myself a trial by fire in the world of modern JS and now I'm regretting it, lol...

The work-in-progress project is up on [GitHub](https://github.com/milesshebar/giveThanks) if you need to see any of the other moving parts, and please don't hesitate to let me know if you have questions! Thanks so much.

**package.json**

```js
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --progress -p",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
},

"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "d3": "^5.0.0",
    "d3pie": "^0.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.1"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery",
                "window.jQuery": "jquery",
                d3: 'd3'
            })
        ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**index.js** (imports only)

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import 'd3pie';
```

**.babelrc**

```js
{
"presets": [ "env" ]
}
```

Comment: Describe the TypeError and show the code surrounding the line it occurs on.

Comment: @CertainPerformance It happens later on in the index.js file: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Which type of pie is typically served at your Thanksgiving dinner? Please select all that apply. - Apple' of undefined" (You can view it here.)[https://github.com/milesshebar/giveThanks/blob/master/index.js] But it must be something to do with the webpack system because this code works in d3 sandboxes, etc.

Comment: That error and file there is the key to your question - your issue probably has nothing to do with the meta setup you posted, so you should probably edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that in `d3.csv("thanksgiving-2015-poll-data.csv", function(data) {`, `data` does not have indicies ranging from 0 to 1057 when you run the script. (maybe check its length? check its type, make sure it's an array?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not so sure that it has nothing to do with the meta setup posted, since the code runs perfectly on an html page with both jQuery and D3 brought in via their respective CDNs. That's why I think it's something to do with the way webpack is preparing the actual 'bundle.js' file that's getting served with the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `d3.csv` function in version 5 of d3 (which you're using in the project) uses *promises* rather than callbacks in order to get the final data. This is how the function should be called:

```
d3.csv("thanksgiving-2015-poll-data.csv").then((data) => {
  var thanksCSV = data;
  // ...
```

When you were calling it as

```
d3.csv("thanksgiving-2015-poll-data.csv", (data) => {
```

that was only a *mapping* function over each row - the argument is meant to be a *row*, not the whole array of rows.

But you have another problem - your `import 'd3pie';` does not give you a `d3pie` constructor to work with. Your import statement should look like this instead:

`import d3pie from 'd3pie';`

But then there's yet another problem - d3pie requires `window.d3` to be defined, which you haven't done. So, below your imports, add:

`window.d3 = d3;`

Then, the pie graph will load properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed feedback. I continued messing around with it and have gotten some of the charts to work! I think I had to put everything inside index.js, plus the d3pie constructor was definitely a blunder. thanks again -- really appreciate your help.